Why does fstreams have 1 cursor for both read & write? (Logically and technically)
Consider the next code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::fstream;

int main()
{
fstream file("text.txt", ios::out| ios::in |ios::trunc| ios::binary);
if (!file)
    throw"ERROR\n";

char y = 't';

streampos get = file.tellg(); // (static_cast<int>(get) == 0)
streampos put = file.tellp(); // (static_cast<int>(put) == 0)

file.write(&y, sizeof(y)); // I'd assume that it will increment *only* the putting
cursor

get = file.tellg(); // Assumingly, the getting cursor will remain the same: 
// (static_cast<int>(get) == 0) . In reality: (static_cast<int>(get) == 1)
put = file.tellp(); // Assumingly and in reality: (static_cast<int>(put) == 1)

return 0;
}

I've been told that the two cursors are independent of each other, and it made sense to me. 2 stream-directions, two cursors. Hence I was very surprised by the results of my checks.
I tried to find answers as to why it happens, but the best I could find is this: . Which says:

Both seekg and seekp have the same effect; using either changes the position of the other.

this:

BTW the repeated seekg and seekp aren't needed. You only need to set the position one time to change modes.

But these answers just note the behaviour, and I don't manage to understand the behaviour's reason. Because, why would a fstream file, that's opened for input and output streams, have 1 cursor for its two streams?
Also, there's
this answer:

The position indicator that marks the current position in the file is affected by both input and output operations.


When you perform a read after a write or vice-versa, the stream should be repositioned back.

Which I'd like to have an explanation to too. Because, in addition to noting what the other answers note, this answer also notes:

If an input operation hit the end-of-file, performing a write directly thereafter is fine.

Which doesn't make sense either, because what he's saying is that reading directly after the end-of-file, is fine..
All of this is unintelligible for me. Hence my question is: Why does the fstream perfom the way it does? Why when maintaining 2 stream-directions, it has only 1 cursor?
Thanks.

This is not limited to fstream, the underlying file object simply has only 1 position that is updated on every read and write operation. This affects other file I/O APIs as well. Some C++ streams do have separate input and output positions, but file streams do not.
